# Can a $C^1$ Riemannian surface be obtained by gluing the boundary of an open subset of $S^2$ to the boundary of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

$\mathbb{E}^n$ denotes coordinate space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard Euclidean metric, and $S^2$ is the $2$-dimensional sphere with its standard Riemannian metric.

**If so inclined, you can skip below to the bold part which shows my question**, but here I'll provide a relevant example for some context. Consider a *sphere cap cone*, by which I mean a surface of revolution that can be parameterized, for some given $t_0 \in (0, \pi)$, as the image of the map $F : \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{E}^3$ defined by

\begin{align*}
F(t, \theta) = (f^1(t), f^2(t) \cos{\theta}, f^2(t) \sin{\theta}),
\end{align*}
where $f^1, f^2$ are the coordinate functions of
\begin{align*}
f(t) = \begin{cases}
(\cos{t}, \sin{t}) & t\in [0, t_0] \\
(\cos{t_0}, \sin{t_0}) + (t - t_0)\cdot(-\sin{t_0}, \cos{t_0}) & t \in [t_0, \infty).
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
If $t_0 < \frac{\pi}{2}$ it looks like a cone with the tip rounded to a spherical cap. If $t_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ it looks like a cylinder with a spherical cap. If $t_0 > \frac{\pi}{2}$ there's a singular point, and it looks like a sphere glued to a double cone. I've created a [Geogebra applet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ekydenkx) to illustrate the shape, though I couldn't get the surface of rotation feature to work with an infinite ray, so I've illustrated a conical frustum with two sphere caps.

Clearly a sphere cap cone is smooth everywhere except possibly where $t = t_0$ (and at the here-irrelevant singular point in the case $t_0 > \frac{\pi}{2}$). At $t_0$ it can be checked that the components of $f$ are differentiable with continuous (actually Lipschitz) derivatives. And so a sphere cap cone is a $C^1$ surface (actually $C^{1, 1}$). Recall that a $C^2$ surface can everywhere be given locally as the graph of a $C^2$ function $G = G(u, v)$, and recall that the Gaussian curvature of the graph of $G$ is $$K = \frac{G_{uu}G_{vv} - G_{uv}^2}{(1 + G_u^2 + G_v^2)^2}.$$
Since this formula only involves first and second derivatives, this shows that the Gaussian curvature of a $C^2$ surface is continuous. We can therefore conclude that the sphere cap cone is not $C^2$, because on the interior of the sphere part the Gaussian curvature is $1$, and on the interior of the cone part the Gaussian curvature is $0$.

The sphere cap cone demonstrates a positive answer to the question, "Can I glue a flat space directly to a piece of a constant positive curvature space in a differentiable way?" It might seem to not be the simplest possible example which does this however, because the flat part is obtained as a quotient of a subspace of $\mathbb{E}^2$, and is not actually isometric to a subspace of $\mathbb{E}^2$; e.g. because geodesics on a cone can intersect more than once.

Edit: I think my original question was ill-posed. The pullback of a metric $g$ (defined on coordinate space) by differentiable $f$ (also defined on coordinate space) has coefficients \[ f^\ast g (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}) = \sum_{a, b} g_{ab}\frac{\partial f^a}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial f^b}{\partial x^j}. \]
If $f$ and $g$ are $C^{k}$ then, except in special cases like $F^\ast (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)$ above, $f^\ast g$ will generally be only $C^{k-1}$. So I think talking about $C^k$ manifolds with $C^l$ metrics may be problematic unless we assume $k \ge l + 1$. There is also a theorem due to Whitney, discussed in Thurston's Three-Dimensional Geometry and Topology book, which says every $C^k$ manifold has a unique maximal compatible smooth structure up to $C^k$ diffeomorphism, which I understand to also mean there's an invertible $C^k$ map $f$ to any given $C^k$ manifold $N$ from some smooth manifold $M$. So if a $C^l$ ($k \ge l + 1$) metric $g$ with some metric requirements is found for a $C^k$ manifold $N$, then $f^\ast g$ will be a $C^l$ metric defined on the smooth manifold $M$ meeting those same metric requirements. Unless I'm mistaken, I think we can therefore assume the underlying manifold is smooth.

I hope the following reformulated question will attract more answers.

**My question is**: Does there exist a connected smooth manifold $M$ with a $C^1$ Riemannian metric such that $M$ decomposes as $M = U \sqcup V \sqcup B$ for $B = \partial U = \partial V$ and for connected open sets $U$ and $V$, such that $(U, g|_{U})$ is $C^1$ isometric
to an open set in $\mathbb{E}^2$ and $(V, g|_{V})$ is $C^1$ isometric to an open set in $S^2$?

---

One thought is that a version of the
Gauss-Bonnet formula may hold on smooth surfaces with $C^1$ metrics.
The (in the case the sphere part is simply connected) the relevant portion of the complement of the image in $\mathbb{E}^2$ of the Euclidean part $U \subset X$ should
topologically be a precompact disk, which should imply the total geodesic curvature of the boundary curve is $2\pi$.
The boundary curve in $X$ also bounds the simply connected sphere part $V$, implying the total geodesic curvature of the boundary plus the area of $V$ is $2\pi$, which implies the area of $V$ is zero.

Another thought, which I think is sufficient in the case that $U$ and $V$ are isometric to disks / complements of disks, applies a result from a paper due to
Deturck and Kazdan called 'Some regularity theorems in riemannian geometry’, which (I believe) here means the regularity of
a $2$-dimensional Riemannian metric is realized by any isothermal coordinates for the metric. Isothermal coordinates for
$X = U \sqcup V \sqcup B$ where $U$ is a spherical disk and $V$ is the complement of a Euclidean disk are obtained by
stereographic projection, and the resulting coordinates are not $C^1$.

I'll try to validate/invalidate these ideas when I have more time, though I of course appreciatively welcome any comments.